# CSS set image background color, not show image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make simple skeleton of image.

```
<img src=""></img> ...
```

Now when I open my page, I see loading pictures. So how can I set for example grey background on this image, and then :

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // remove css which overwrited image with grey color.
});
```

something like

```
img {
    background-color: grey !important;
}
```

not works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The CSS properties are for an element with the class `.img`. Try  `img { ... }` instead.

Comment: `img` tags are self-closing void tags, they can contain no nested elements/child nodes (an empty tag) so the closing/end tag `</img>` is not permitted - just a heads up **<img> - HTML | MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Changed from `.img` to `img`. Anyway same

Comment: @DisplayName can you add CSS to the image.?

Comment: Why don't you declare the `background-color` rule to a class selector that you just remove in your jQuery snippet using `.removeClass('the-class')` - you'll probably need to declare `display: inline-block` or `display: block` on this class selector (with your `background-color` and possibly `width` & `height` properties too) so that you can actually see the space the `img` is occupying int the document flow while it loads the image defined in `src` - because until then the `img` won't have any `height` or `width`, or `block` type properties to display the `background-color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a div that contains only your image and assign it a grey background

```
#container{
  background-color:grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

Then using jQuery you could append to the html document your image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#container').append(
    '<img id=img_id src=" ">'
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img id="image" src="">

$('#image').css("background-color","grey");
$('#image').on("load", function() {
    $('#image').css("background-color","transparent");
});
```

Basically you set background color and remove it when your picture loads.